# create a stand alone database in lua

Tags: database, lua

I've never done databases before but I know that you can create them on MySQL, the thing is that I want to be able to write/read a database locally and not have to send/receive any information online as it would be too slow for what I need.

Is there a way to create a stand alone database (possibly on MySQL then downloading it) and write/read from it using LUA?

Thanks for any information, as I say, never touched databases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. 
You can download [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/), which is a simple `SQL` relational DB. Basically this type of DB is just a file (`.db` extension), so you can have it locally on you PC and also exchange it between many machines easily.

From a Lua standpoint, what you need is a library to access your DB and I think [LuaSQLIte3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki) is the best option to go with. Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395072/how-do-i-create-an-sqlite3-database-using-luasql) post for a basic example on this.

IMO using `lua` in conjunction with `sqlite3` is one of the best choices when one wants to have a (light) SQL-based DB locally, without the added "complexity" of a more commercially used DB (e.g.`postgres`).